# How can I programmatically access a specific Run after adding it to a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to be able to programmatically access a specific run after adding it to a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock but I cannot set the Name of a Run because the Name property is read only (allows get but not set).

Each run will be created dynamically through a loop (not at design time (xaml)), and I will not know the index (i-th) as they may be created in any order. I would know a word or keyword that would be in a run, but otherwise I have no other way to identify one individual run from another.

How can I programmatically find and access a specific Run that was added to a TextBlock, when I click a button?

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

var myTextBlock = new TextBlock(); 

var someRun = new Run
{   
     Text = "Some run to start"
};

myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(someRun)

var aRandomRun = new Run
{   
     Text = "A random run with some words"
};

myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(aRandomRun)

var anotherRun = new Run
{   
     Text = "Another run, could be anything"
};

myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(anotherRun)

private void GetTextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the text of any of these above runs in myTextBlock

    // I tried "FindName" but since I cannot set the the name of the Run, I cannot use FindName to find the Run
    var anotherRunText = myTextBlock.Inlines.Where(x=> x.FindName
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Because if you know which run you want to get you can just define that run as variable in the .cs file. Otherwise you could take the i-th element from the `myTextBlock.Inlines`. You could also define this textblock, or the runs in the resources of the `xaml` file you are working in, or in the `app.xaml` resources. Defining the `Run` 's there enables you to set a name to the runs.

Comment: @Leander. Thanks. Each run will be created dynamically through a loop (not at design time (xaml)), and I will not know the index (i-th) as they may be created in any order. I would know a word or keyword that would be in a run, but otherwise I have no other way to identify one individual run from another. I updated my question with this information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have provided an answer based on this info, please respond if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, both approaches in your answer are good but the FindInlineText is sufficient for my needs. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only way of distinguishing the `Run`'s from each other is by their text. You could indeed use what you have tried already, however instead of using the `Name` property you use the text property:

```cs
string FindInlineText(string keyword)
{
    string anotherRunText = ((Run)myTextBlock.Inlines.First(i => ((Run)i).Text.Contains(keyword))).Text;
    return anotherRunText;
}
```

It does not seem possible to approach this in another way, since `Run.Name` is get only in code behind, and although the `Tag` property should be inherited from the `FrameworkContentElement` class it is not available to set.

If you do need to use another identifier to distinguish the text elements from each other, you may look into using a horizontal `StackPanel` and multiple `TextBlock` instead:

```cs
StackPanel stack = new StackPanel { Orientation = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal };
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    stack.Children.Add(new TextBlock 
    { 
        Name = $"inlineblock_{i}", 
        Text = i.ToString() 
    }); 
}
```

And now you are ofcourse able to get the text of the correct `TextBlock` by using:

```cs
string certainText = ((TextBlock)stack.Children.First(i => ((TextBlock)i).Name == certainName)).Text;
```